# Foreground service and Android Wear notification

Tags: java, android, service

I have a Foreground Service that displays a status notification on the phone about the connection and some server data.
I would like to show this info in the Android Wear device too, but i get one notification on the Wear device and 2 in the Android Phone.
This is the code:

```
public void createNotification(String text)
{
    int notificationId = 001;
    Notification not=null;

    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);



    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    not=notificationBuilder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId,not );
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, not);
}
```

Comment: Please share if you find a solution

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this you will have to build a wear app which creates and shows the notification on the wearable. Use the [Wearable Data Layer API](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) to send the content from your mobile to the wearable. Then you can show a notification containing the information directly on the wearable.